# I had requirement like this

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

Question table contains:

| id | question | questionBankId | rightAnswerMark | wrongAnswerMark | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

QuestionBank table contains:

| id | questionBankName | standardId | sectionId | subjectId | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

So in question table i have to add multiple questions with same questionBankId and same  question should not be repeated.how do i add multiple questions with same questionBankId and same question should not repeat.

Comment: create unique constraint on questions.

Comment: Select a better title for your question. Your question does not give any good information to users.

Answer (score 1):

You Must Create Relation Between 2 Tables , For this Issue You Should Set A @ManyToOne RelationShip From Question To QuestionBank.

Write This In Class Question:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="question_bank_id")
private QuestionBank questionBank;
```